# Is it possible to overwrite the positioning of a twitter bootstrap popover on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am currently trying to change the position of my popover depending on the position of the element which triggered the popover.

The Problem is that I initialize all of my popovers with a static positioning (See my example, below). I want to change or set the position on the fly, directly when I hover the element which triggered the popover. Is this possible?

```
$(".timelineTour")
         .popover({
             offset: 10,
             trigger: 'manual',
             animate: false,
             html: true,
             placement: 'bottom',
             template: '<div class="popover">' + 
                         '<div class="arrow"></div>' + 
                         '<div class="popover-inner">' + 
                           '<h3 class="popover-title"></h3>' + 
                           '<div class="popover-content"><p></p></div>' + 
                         '</div>' +
                       '</div>'



        }).mouseenter(function(){
          /* examine position*/
          /* ........        */

          $(this).popover({
             offset: 10,
             trigger: 'manual',
             animate: false,
             html: true,
             placement: 'right',
             template: '<div class="popover">' + 
                         '<div class="arrow"></div>' + 
                         '<div class="popover-inner">' + 
                           '<h3 class="popover-title"></h3>' + 
                           '<div class="popover-content"><p></p></div>' + 
                         '</div>' +
                       '</div>'
           });
          $(this).popover('show');         
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bootstrap 2.1 at least (though I believe the feature has been there for a while now), [options for popovers can be passed via `data-` attributes](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers). So you can simply include a `data-placement="top"` for popover you want to be shown at the top, and so on.